# Spark sql concat combination

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Given the following table:

```
 Element
----------
    A
    B
    C
```

I want to generate concat combination without repetitions

result I want:

```
A
B
C
A + B
A + C
B + C
A + B + C
```

My solution right now:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM(

SELECT  T.Element AS CONCAT_PROD
FROM    TABLE AS T 

UNION ALL

SELECT CONCAT(T.Element, ' + ', T2.Element) AS CONCAT_PROD
FROM    TABLE AS T 
JOIN TABLE AS T2 ON T2.Element > T.Element

UNION ALL

CONCAT(T.Element, ' + ', T2.Element, ' + ', T3.Element) AS CONCAT_PROD
FROM    TABLE AS T 
JOIN TABLE AS T2 ON T2.Element> T.Element
JOIN TABLE AS T3 ON T3.Element> T2.Element 

)
```

But this solution does not properly work if there are values insert into the table in the future. Is there any way I can make the solution to be dynamically adjust to values in the table?

Comment: Any update on this? Have you gone with a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do this kind of join dynamically without writing dynamic sql. But if you can presuppose the maximum number of values `n` in the table and write `n` self join like this, this will support three more values added to the table (A-F).

```
with cte as (
    select 0 id, '' Element
    union all select 1, 'A'
    union all select 2, 'B'
    union all select 3, 'C'
),

final as ( 
    select concat(
                f.Element, case when nullif(f.id,0) is null then '' else ' + ' end,
                e.Element, case when nullif(e.id,0) is null then '' else ' + ' end,
                d.Element, case when nullif(d.id,0) is null then '' else ' + ' end,
                c.Element, case when nullif(c.id,0) is null then '' else ' + ' end,
                b.Element, case when nullif(b.id,0) is null then '' else ' + ' end,
                a.Element
            ) combined
    from cte a
    left join cte b on a.id > b.id
    left join cte c on b.id > c.id
    left join cte d on c.id > d.id
    left join cte e on d.id > e.id
    left join cte f on e.id > f.id
) 

select * from final order by len(combined), 1
```

Otherwise I would suggest pulling the unique values out and iterating over them in Python instead